# Access angular Singleton serice function in other class scope

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

i have a Singleton service class in Angular :

Comment: You don't need to add extra declaration for service above constructor.

Comment: Also use `this` with service variable.

Comment: when calling it without adding it in the constructor it says it's undefined

Comment: You do need it in the constructor, you're correct. Please could you add your module code? Looks like you've just missed out adding the service into the providers

Comment: Have you added `TripService` to `app.module` `providers` array?

Comment: @Nitika no it's not added there where to add it please ?

Comment: delete this line `tripService:TripService` and also mark in constructor like this `private tripService:TripService`

Comment: In `app.module.ts`, there must be arrays for `declarations`, `imports`, likewise add `providers` if it's not there. `providers: [TripService]`.

Comment: ok i just added it there and it's still the same error

Comment: Can you add your code to stackblitz?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
export class TripDetailsPage implements OnInit {
  
  currentTrip:Trip = new Trip("","")
  constructor(private router:Router, private tripService:TripService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.currentTrip = this.tripService.getCurrentTrip();
    console.log(this.currentTrip);
  }

  switchToTab(path: string) {
    this.router.navigate(['home/trips/trip-details/' + path]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create an instance of your class (in this case your service) and then you can access any public methods and variables in the root class. in order to create an instance of your class, you need your `constructor` to know about this.

`constructor(private router:Router, private tripService:TripService) { }`

now an instance of your class is available in your component and you can access that using `this.tripService`. keep that in mind the `tripService` is up to you and you can declare any name you desire.

```js
export class TripDetailsPage implements OnInit {
  
  constructor(private router:Router, private tripService:TripService) { }

  ngOnInit() {}
}
```

Extra note:
if you want your service not to be a singleton service (which you can use access in your whole application), you need to provide your component in your service.